# Command line arguments in Visual C++ in VS2010

Tags: visual-c++

How do I access the command line argument that I set in my project.
for example if I give following input to command line "abc def ghi"
then how do I access them using argc &/or argv.

I am getting some integer values if I am accessing them via argv[i] or *argv[i]
Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have that "gives you integer values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them like in this example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  for(int i=0;i<argc;i++) {
   std::cout<<argv[i];
  }
}
```

The cause of the error you are experiencing probably is that you use the TCHAR form of the main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]);
```

In Visual C++ per default UNICODE is defined. Therefore you have to use std::wcout for output instead of std::cout.

This is  the way it probably will work:

```
  for(int i=0;i<argc;i++) {
   std::wcout<<argv[i];
  }
```

Comment: thanks I got the mistake. Instead of using _tmain and _TCHAR I used main and char. and I got to know one more point that: by default first command line argument is **path to .exe file** ... thanks :)